# PowerQuery How to Delete text after first lower case letter in a string

Tags: powerquery

I have a table of data which contains multiple cells with the following format:

PRO-PLAS AFRICA EXPOPlastic Machinery & Materials Exhibition. PRO-PLAS AFRICA EXPO features Plastics processing machinery, Chillers, Converting equipment, Extrusion equipment, Feeders, Processing aids, Recycling equipment, Various materials, Blow moulding machinery

I want to transform the string to remove everything from the first lower case letter, so I am left with:

PRO-PLAS AFRICA EXPOP

Then remove the last letter in the string to leave:

PRO-PLAS AFRICA EXPO

I have tried using the following:

```
'#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "allCaps", each 
        Text.Combine(
            List.Accumulate(Text.Split([Column1]," "),
                            {},
                            (state, current)=>  
                                if List.ContainsAny(
                                        Text.ToList(current),
                                            {"0".."9","a".."z",",",":","?","/","\"," "}) 
                                then state 
                                else state & {current}),", "))'
```

with [column1] substituted for the relevant table column, which delivers:

PRO-PLAS  AFRICA  &  PRO-PLAS  AFRICA  EXPO

I can work out that this is because the first occurrence of "EXPOPlastic" contains upper and lower case letters..

I have also tried "text.remove" to get rid of all lower case letters, but this leaves the upper case at the start of each word giving:

PRO-PLAS AFRICA EXPOP M & M E. PRO-PLAS AFRICA EXPO P, C, C, E, F, P, R V , B

The initial lower case letter is in a different position in each cell.

is there a solution to this?

Comment: Can you share input data in tabular format and expected output. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each Text.Start([Column1],Text.PositionOfAny([Column1],{"a".."z"})-1))
```